# Problema con java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: numberformat

soy nuevo en la programación y estoy haciendo un programa que resuelva la formula general, pero cuando lo ejecuto me marca esto:

Este es el codigo que estoy haciendo:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
public class FormulaGeneral {
    String NumeroA;
    String NumeroB;
    String NumeroC;
    float Resultado;
    float Raiz;
    int Interior;
    public FormulaGeneral() {
        int NumeralA=Integer.parseInt(NumeroA);
        int NumeralB=Integer.parseInt(NumeroB);
        int NumeralC=Integer.parseInt(NumeroC);
        NumeroA=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escribe el numero A");
        NumeroB=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escribe el numero B");
        NumeroC=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escribe el numero C");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El resultado es "+Resultado);
        Resultado=-NumeralB+Raiz/2;
        Interior=NumeralB-4*NumeralA*NumeralC;
        double Raiz = Math.sqrt(Interior);
        }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new FormulaGeneral();
}
}
```

Cuando compilo me dice que está bien pero al ejecutarlo me dice esto:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:614)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at FormulaGeneral.<init>(FormulaGeneral.java:11)
    at FormulaGeneral.main(FormulaGeneral.java:23)

Process completed.
```

Acepto criticas o sugerencias para cambiar o modificar el codigo y espero que me puedan ayudar a saber que pasa.

Cita en bloque

Comment: Título = idea escencial. Cuerpo del mensaje = Contiene los detalles. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ¿Qué te asegura que `NumeroA` tiene algún valor? ¿Dónde se lo asignas? Y pasa lo mismo con los otros...

Comment: 1.-Lo se, después de arreglar eso le agregaré un trycatch para que marque el error de que no puso un numero, pero ahora lo que no entiendo y lo que necesito saber es por que me dice: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null" cuando intento ejecutarlo; 2.- Con JOptionPane pido los números que luego los transformo con Integer.

Comment: Pues está muy claro el mensaje: estás intentando convertir a número una variable que tiene valor `null`. Los `String` `NumeroA`, `NumeroB` y `NumeroC` tienen valor null cuando ejecutas el `parseInt`. Primero conviertes los números y luego los pides?

Comment: Entonces era la sintaxis del codigo, gracias por la aclaración a mi duda.